# Access JSON Child Node via Variable - JSON2HTML

Tags: javascript, html, json, node.js, json2html

i got the following transform template:

```
   var transform = {'<>':'li','html':'${name} - ${version} - ${licenseSources.package.sources[0].license}'};
```

now i want to transform a JSON into a HTML with json2html:

```
var html = json2html.transform(data,transform);
```

JSON looks like this:

```
{
    "id": "xxx",
    "name": "xxx",
    "version": "0.0.14-SNAPSHOT",
    "repository": "xxx",
    "directory": "./",
    "type": "(none)",
    "licenseSources": {
        "package": {
            "sources": [{
                    "license": "BSD",
                    "url": "(none)"
                }
            ]
        },
        "license": {
            "sources": [{
                    "filePath": "xxx",
                    "text": "xxx"
                }, {
                    "filePath": "xxx",
                    "text": "xxx"
                }
            ]
        },
        "readme": {
            "sources": [{
                    "filePath": "xxx",
                    "text": "xxx"
                }
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

I want to access licenseSouce.package.sources.license = "bsd" over the transform variable. But i can't figure out the notation.

Can someone help?

Thx in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out:

```
${licenseSources.package.sources.0.license}
```